# tidyr separate only first n instances

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data.frame in R, which, for simplicity, has one column that I want to separate.  It looks like this:

```
V1
Value_is_the_best_one
This_is_the_prettiest_thing_I've_ever_seen
Here_is_the_next_example_of_what_I_want
```

My **real** data is very large (millions of rows), so I'd like to use tidyr's separate function (because it's amazingly fast) to separate out JUST the first few instances.  I'd like the result to be the following:

```
V1       V2     V3     V4 
Value    is     the    best_one
This     is     the    prettiest_thing_I've_ever_seen
Here     is     the    next_example_of_what_I_want
```

As you can see, the separator is `_` the V4 column can have different numbers of the separators.  I want to keep V4 (not discard it), but not have to worry about how much stuff is in there.  There will always be four columns (i.e. none of my rows have only V1-V3).

Here is my starting tidyr command I've been working with:

```
separate(df, V1, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), sep="_")
```

This gets rid of V4 (and spits out warnings, which isn't the biggest deal).

Comment: Do you just need `extra = "merge"`?

Comment: @aosmith Yes, thank you.  I read the documentation like 10 times and somehow kept misunderstanding that!  Please put it into an answer!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need the `extra` argument with the `"merge"` option.  This allows only as many splits as you have new columns defined.

```
separate(df, V1, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), extra = "merge")

     V1 V2  V3                             V4
1 Value is the                       best_one
2  This is the prettiest_thing_I've_ever_seen
3  Here is the    next_example_of_what_I_want
```

Comment: What if you want to merge the other way? eg, let's say that you've got "John Q Public." I want to break it into two strings: "John Q" and "Public." Is there a straightforward way to do that, other than manually splitting and subsetting?

Comment: @DavidBruceBorenstein It sounds like you need to set the `sep` argument so you only split on the last space.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another option with `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, V1, into = paste0("V", 1:4), "([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(.*)")
#      V1 V2  V3                             V4
# 1 Value is the                       best_one
# 2  This is the prettiest_thing_I've_ever_seen
# 3  Here is the    next_example_of_what_I_want
```

Another option is `stri_split` from `library(stringi)` where we can specify the number of splits

```
library(stringi)
do.call(rbind, stri_split(df1$V1, fixed="_", n=4))
```