# separate in tidyr, error please supply column name

Tags: r, tidyr

The   dataset that is used in many R tutorials has an initial column with no header that lists the names of the cars, according to make and model.

I was trying to separate the make and the model of car.

First I made a column of the first, headerless column, called "names".

```
> mtcars$names <- rownames(mtcars)

> rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
```

This gave me a column that was a character vector with the following results:

```
> mtcars$names
```

With the following output:

```
[1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"    
[3] "Datsun 710"          "Hornet 4 Drive"
```

etc

I then tried this:

```
separate(mtcars, colname = names, into = c('make', 'model')
```

and got the following error:

Error: Please supply column name

Comment: The argument is `col`, not `colname`.

Comment: If the issue is splitting on the first space, you can use `extra = "merge"` in `separate` rather than working out the regex.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126634/r-tidyr-separate-only-first-n-instances/37126832)

Answer (score 0):

```
separate(mtcars, col = names, into = c('make', 'model'), sep = '')
```

The "Vaillant" does not have a make description, but I think this is what you were asking for.

Comment: This will do it, but to make it complete please address the real issue of OP attempting to pass an incorrect argument name (`colname` where it should be `col`), which is what triggered the error.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299978/splitting-a-string-on-the-first-space]

Here you can find a much better solution

Comment: How could you tell that the Valiant did not have a make description. To get separate  to  work (along with extra = 'merge' )  I had to delete that row.

Comment: @ErnieCranks Is your tidyr version up to date?  `separate` works fine for me on this example, just puts `NA` in the second column for Valiant and gives a warning.